# Java Hibernate (Exception)

Tags: java, исключения

Подскажите причину вызова исключения:

```
hibernate.cfg.xml

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"> root </property>
        <property name="connection.password"> root </property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    static {

            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                    applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Main

```
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
       SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }
```

И само исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2005)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1986)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 6 more
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавление cfg в директорию resources возникло:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:212)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:58)
at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Может hibernate.cfg.xml лежит не там где надо?

Comment: Он находится в одной директории с HibernateUtil и Main.java (src/main/java/com/hibernate.cfg.xml)

Comment: Попробуйте перенести его в src/main/resources

Comment: Перенес, не помогло:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ, нужно было править HibernateUtil.java

```
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."  + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Файл .cfg должен находиться в директории /resources

Может кому-то поможет...)